# Creating an array without keys in a loop

Tags: php, arrays

This might be a brain fart, since it's a late day, but I'm stuck here.

I need to take a $_POST value from a select box. (It's an array), and convert it to a simple array that doesn't have any keys.

Here's the print_r from the item:

`Array ( [0] => 19 [1] => 18 [2] => 21 )`

Problem is, I need an array that looks like this:

`Array(19,18,21)`

Whenever I try to foreach() through the form field, I have to do something like this:

`$row[] = $val;`

But that leaves me with a numerical index.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: you say you need an Array(19,18,21) but that kind of an array has a numerical index...the only other option is to treat the Array like a dictionary with keys

Comment: @eat_a_lemon: The "problem" here is, that PHP treat both as the same. An array in PHP is a dictionary (more detailed: A hashmap) with integer keys starting by `0`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you can't have an array without keys.

```
Array(19,18,21)
```

this array has keys 0,1 and 2.

Comment: There is a semantical difference between keys and indices, even if php doesnt take care of it.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out it was a problem with the type anyways. I feel dumb.

Answer (score 10):

Arrays (in PHP) always have (at least) numeric indices. However, you can extract the values via [array_values()](http://php.net/array-values). This returns only the values of the given array. It of course has indices, but they are continous and they are numeric. Thats the most simple array representation you can have in PHP.

Update, just to make that clear: You cannot have an array without indices in PHP (as far as I know in any other language thats quite the same), because internaly arrays are always hashmaps and hashmaps always needs a key. The "most common key" are indices. You cannot omit the "keys". On the other side I dont the any reason why one should want it. If you dont want to use the keys, just dont use the keys and thats really all. PHP is quite gentle in this point.

Comment: Just a note, calling something an ```array``` implies order, while ```hash``` usually implies the presence of string keys (in php these two structures are the same).  Usually in other languages what the OP is talking about is called a ```set```, or ```unordered list```.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you are going to get is to combine so your keys are your values

```
array_combine($array1,$array1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try
Array_column(the name of the array, then the positions you want to get).
Then print_r (result)