# Multidimensional array join with child items and echo out

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, csv, multidimensional-array

I have the following format:

```
Array
(
[id] => 325
[type] => 
[p_type] => 
[fees] => 
[sku] => 412
[amountt] => 
)
Array
(
[id] => 325
[type] => 
[p_type] => Initial
[fees] => 
[sku] => 412
[amount] => 2.22)

Array
(
[id] => 325
[type] => 
[p_type] => Shipping
[fees] => 
[sku] => 412
[amount] =>0.22
)

Array
(
[id] => 325
[type] => shipping_add
[p_type] => 
[fees] => 
[sku] => 412
[amount] => 0.50 )

Array
(
[id] => 325
[type] => comms
[p_type] => 
[fees] => 
[sku] => 412
[amount] => 1.22
)
```

I can get each value and display back via say:

```
$arr[id] = $idCars;
```

and display that in my theme quite easily, however what I'd like to do is actually merge the data - so I have only one array entry for that ID, with a child->sub array, any ideas?

Requested array format:

```
[0] => 325 412 
[1] => 325 412 Initial 2.22 
[2] => 325 412 comms -1.22 
[3] => 325 412 Shipping -0.22 
[4] => 325 412 Shipping_add -0.50 
[5] => 326 444 Shipping -1.45 
[6] => 326 444 Initial 0.91
```

I reformat this via:

```
$result = array();
$result[id] = $id;
$result[type] =  $type;
$result[p_type] =  $ptype;
$result[fees] = $fees;
$result[sku] = $sku;
$result[amount] =  $amount;
```

and so on ...

Comment: Can  you show the full array? You've only shown sub level arrays.

Comment: The sub array is better formatted for me to reuse, the large array has structure similar to:

    [0] => 325    412 
    [1] => 325    412   Initial    2.22
    [2] => 325    412   comms    -1.22
    [3] => 325    412   Shipping    -0.22
    [4] => 325    412   Shipping_add   -0.50
    [5] => 326    444   Shipping   -1.45                                       
    [6] => 326    444   Initial   0.91

Comment: Can you edit your question and add that info/the full array? It's hard to see what your array is doing, i.e. you state "*I can get each value and display back via say `$arr[id] = $idCars;`*" but we cannot see that with the info you have provided. Need more info. It's likely you can do a loop on the array and make a new array with whatever data you need

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking to do, but I'll give it a try. If you want the subarrays to be keyless, all arrays in PHP have keys. See: [Creating an array without keys in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750353/creating-an-array-without-keys-in-a-loop)

If you are still adamant you want the output to be in the suggested format, you could store each subarray as a string like this:

```
$new_arr = array();
$count = 0;

foreach ($arr as $val) {

    $new_arr[$count] = $val['id'].' '.$val['type'].' '.$val['p_type'].' '.$val['fees'].' '.$val['sku'].' '.$val['amount'];
    $count++;

}

$arr = $new_arr;
```