# iterator_to_array without keys

Tags: php, php-7.2

I use **iterator_to_array** to convert a mysql select query to array:

```
$array = iterator_to_array($ddObj, FALSE);
```

I got this result:

```
array([0] => 'red',[1] => 'white')
```

but I need:

```
 array('red','white')
```

I try with **array_values($array);** but without success.

Comment: have you tried `print_r(array('red', 'white'));`? It's exactly the same as the result you are getting.

Comment: *but I need:* and that is exactly what you got.

Comment: Already closevoted but here is a dup for anyone to vote with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750353/creating-an-array-without-keys-in-a-loop

Comment: @Andreas well spotted! I'll add that one to my list.